# GAS: onFormSubmit trigger issue with sending messages (but they are in "sent" folder)

Tags: google-apps-script

I can see all messages which were generated by google apps script in Gmail "sent" folder but I didn't received them in other test account. But if I create a message manually - I receive it (in the test account).
Could you please give me any ideas what's wrong is it. It looks that script works properly. 
Document's Trigger: Event: "**From spreadsheet - On form submit**"

**Next day update:**
Now I see that this is a not already question about GAS (my code works) but now my question already about some settings somewhere...
I have seen when I disabled the option "**Restrict to users in  and trusted domains**" (https://support.google.com/a/answer/6160020)  in the Google Form's Settings - I started to receive notifications generated by script...

Do you know how to keep this restriction and to have working onFormSubmit trigger? Thank you!
[image: Google Form's Settings: Restrict Users]

**Big Edit:**

Sorry all, my fault in providing the source code. Function **sendNotification(data)** is called not directly as a onFormSubmit event handler, but from inside **onFormSubmit(event)** function - which I use as a onFormSubmit Event handler. In this case sendNotification(data) function received my own prepared data object - not an event object which received the event handler function.

```
//onFormSubmit Event Handler:
function onFormSubmit(event) {
  ...
  sendNotification(data) 
}

/**
 * Sending a HTML Notification Message to all recipients in the Email List
 */
function sendNotification(data) {
  try {

    Logger.log("-------------------------------- in sendNotification") 

    var template = HtmlService.createTemplateFromFile('NotificationEmail');
    template.data = data;
    var htmlOutput = template.evaluate();
    var htmlMessage = htmlOutput.getContent() 


    var notifySheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("Notifications");
    var notifyRange = notifySheet.getDataRange(); 

    var addresses = notifyRange.getValues(); 
    addresses.shift(); //skip Headers (first row)

    Logger.log("addresses: " + addresses);


    //Loop through all Addresses:
    for (i in addresses) {
      var row = addresses[i];
      var address = row[0]; //1st column  <-----
      if(address) {
        Logger.log("address: " + address);

        //MailApp.sendEmail(emailAddress, subject, message);            
        MailApp.sendEmail({
          name: "notification",
          to: address,
          subject: data.emailTitle,
          htmlBody: htmlMessage,
          //noReply: true,
          inlineImages: {
            logoImage: data.logoImage
          }
        });

      }    
    }
    Logger.log("-------------------------------- end of sendNotification")

  } catch (err) {
    Logger.log(err.toString());
  }
}
```

**Update** (added a screenshot of the Script's Permissions on the Suite Developer Hub https://script.google.com):
[image]

**Update 2**
(Edited)Source Code of the original message:

```
    Delivered-To: admin@g<company_name>.com
    Received: by ..... with SMTP id .....;
            Tue, 2 Apr 2019 07:20:12 -0700 (PDT)
    DKIM-Signature: v=1; a=rsa-sha256; c=relaxed/relaxed;.....
    X-Google-DKIM-Signature: v=1; a=rsa-sha256; c=relaxed/relaxed;........
    X-Google-Smtp-Source: ........
    MIME-Version: 1.0
    X-Received: by ...... with SMTP id ......; Tue, 02 Apr 2019 07:20:12 -0700 (PDT)
    Message-ID: <000000000000.......@google.com>
    Date: Tue, 02 Apr 2019 14:20:12 +0000
    Subject: ......
    From: ...... admin@g<company_name>.com
    To: ....@gmail.com
    Content-Type: multipart/related;
```

**Update 3**

```
function onFormSubmit(event) {
  try {

    Logger.log("onFormSubmit trigger runs-------------------------------------")

    //PREVENT AN ERROR: Service invoked too many times in a short time: exec qps. Try Utilities.sleep(1000) between calls.
    Utilities.sleep(300);

    var submitterEmail = Session.getEffectiveUser().getEmail();
    var submitRow = event.range.rowStart;
    var spreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
    var sheet = spreadsheet.getSheetByName("Form Responses 1");

    ...

    //exec Log:
    var execLog = spreadsheet.getSheetByName("ExecLog");
    var execLastRow = execLog.getLastRow();

    //setCellValue(sheet, row, col, newValue) 
    setCellValue(execLog, execLastRow+1, 1, JSON.stringify(event));

    ....
    var data = { ... }

    //Sending HTML Messages:
    sendSubmitterConfirmation(data); //Submitter's confirmation
    sendNotification(data); //Notifications
    sendRequestToApprove(data); //Requests to approve

  } catch (err) {
    Logger.log(err.toString());
  }
}
```

"ExecLog" sheet contains the source code of the event object:

```
{
  "authMode": {},
  "values": [
    "4/2/2019 14:00:24",
    "admin@<COMPANY_NAME>.com",
    "test",
    "test",
    "test",
    "01-01-01",
    "test@test.com"
  ],
  "namedValues": {
    QUESTIONS.....
  },
  "range": {
    "columnStart": 1,
    "rowStart": 2,
    "rowEnd": 2,
    "columnEnd": 10
  },
  "source": {},
  "triggerUid": "XXXXX"
}
```

Comment: Have you checked your spam folder in test account?

Comment: outlook.office.com : Junk Email ... nothing :(

Comment: I have checked right now: unfortunately there are no messages on other accounts: my own gmail and company's gmail as well.

Comment: When you look at the sent emails, what email address were they sent to?

Comment: Hi J.G. I have added (edited) the header  of the original message in the body of my question. Maybe it will be useful... I didn't see anything special in the source code of the original message

Comment: Does sending the email to yourself work?

Comment: I used the same admin account to create a script and to fill out the form - when I uses noreply option - I didn't see anything, I disabled noreply option and I see messages in sent folder but they haven't been sent to anywhere until I disabled domain restriction in Form's Settings

Answer (score 2):

When the function `sendNotification(data)` is attached to the onFormSubmit event the parameter `data` gets replaced with the event object.

[Event Object for OnFormSubmit](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/events#form-submit)

Comment: Have a look on my Update 3 with some part of source code of the event handler function and the source code of the event object (saved into the "execLog" sheet)

Comment: thank you Cooper, I have added extra code to show that everything should work and also I don't know how to add the source code in comments. And sendNotification(data) function is not called directly. Sorry please, my fault

Comment: Oh I see, your saying that sendNotifications(data) is not the triggerHandler.  Sorry, I assumed incorrectly.

Comment: I woundn't use this `var execLastRow = execLog.getLastRow();` I would use the values array in the form Submit event object because there is no guarantee that the last row is the one you want if your getting rapid form submissions.

Comment: Hi Cooper. Thank you very much! You are right - you pointed on my mistake - I didn't mentioned very important part of code

Comment: I created the execLog sheet after asking this question - this is a temporary solution. You are totally right about using rowStart from Submit event

Comment: I think you'll want to use the values parameter from [onFormSubmit Object](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/events#form-submit)

Comment: Yes. Correct. I wrap values parameter from onFormSubmit Event object into the data parameter of sendNotification(data) function. And I see the generated messages in my (admin) gmail "sent" folder but I don't receive generated messages on any address.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/191134/discussion-between-cooper-and-alex-pilugin).

Comment: I checked API Permissions and didn't find my Google Apps Script which uses MailApp: https://admin.google.com/AdminHome?fral=1#Oauth2ScopeManagement:subtab=installed